# Cannot create a DbSet for '...' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dbset

I have a problem with entity framework, 
The wreid is: my local machine with windows 10 and asp.net core SDK 2.1.802 work fine, but VPS with ubuntu 18.04, ASP.Net core SDK 2.1.802 is not.
here is my DbContext, i already put property.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{       
    public DbSet<Contractor> Contractors { get; set; }
....
```

but anything call to: `_dbContext.Contractors` on VPS got error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'Contractor' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
....
```

the VPS health is good. cpu: 5%, ram 40%.
And i see the wreid in my log on VPS:

```
 at Portal.Controllers.ContractorController.All() in D:\petProject\src\Portal\Controllers\ContractorController.cs:line 47
```

the directory `D:\petProject\src\Portal\Controllers\ContractorController.cs` is my code folder on my local machine.
but i always run this web on a terminal that SSH on my VPS.
Please help me!

Comment: The only thing I've found is [this git issue thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13174). Other solutions are about `IdentityDbContext`.

Comment: thank man, but they can not reproduce this bug. seem it is the mystic thing